# Are there multiple representations of the same target value? Are they interchangable?

Tags: difficulty, block-header

The block target in Bitcoin is encoded in block headers as a [24 bit integer raised to an 8 bit exponent:](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Difficulty#How_is_difficulty_stored_in_blocks.3F)

```
int(nBits[1:4]) * 2 ** (8 * (int(nBits[0]) - 3))
```

Are there multiple `nBits` representations of the same target value? Are they interchangeable? That is, could a miner choose any of them?

Comment: Yes there would be multiple representations but I don't know if they are valid or not. I don't know if the target is binary matched in the core client or if it is just compared to be of at least `n` difficulty.